# How to share request id in socket.io to another files with respect to each request

Tags: node.js, socket.io, local-storage, local

I want to share request specific information to each file in the socket application. I am using socket.io in node js. May I know, how to do this. There is no direct libraries available to do it. Can any one give some suggestions..?

Comment: can you please provide an example of what you want to achieve, or show what you currently have, it's easier to help you this way.

Comment: I want to track request id coming from client on each request which is unique per connection and I want to add them to my logs. so that, I can track logs with respect to each request.

Comment: why don't you just send the request id as a parameter to your loggnig function. Please show in code what you want to achieve, it's not clear.

Comment: I am trying to achieve this without sharing the request id in each method. Is there any global way to do this..? Like, continuation-local-storage..?

This application is already developed and I don't want to change each method to achieve this. So I am trying ways to find any solution without changing each log line

Comment: Use classes, and pass it to the constructor only.

Comment: If we pass like that, then if multiple concurrent connections running, then values may override from one request to another request. Right..? Let me know, if I am wrong.

Comment: No, you're wrong, because you create a new class **instance** per connection.

Comment: okay.. But in my case, few classes created objects without getting connection from client itself. i.e. few methods are using with out getting connection and few methods are using after getting connection. So, I am using same instance that is already created at the time of running node application. There is no instances creating after connection established.